# How to conditionally set a function argument type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a generic function I need to call in 2 places

```
const functionA = (arg1, deleteFunction) => {
 deleteFunction(arg1)
}
```

when I call it in the two different places I pass in a different `deleteFunction` each time. these `deleteFunctions` then update redux but they require different types so I'm getting errors

I was wondering if for `arg1` I could specify what type it should be based on properties it contains. something like this

```
const functionA = (arg1: arg1.hasSomeProperty ? Arg1Types : Arg1OtherType, deleteFunction) => {
 deleteFunction(arg1)
}
```

obviously this doesn't work but the 2 deleteFunctions have different types (one has `Arg1Types`the other has `Arg1OtherTypes`

might be going about it in completely the wrong way. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function overload, either using overload syntax with the `function` keyword, or using an interface with `const` an an arrow function as in your question.

Overload syntax:

```typescript
function functionA(arg: Arg1Type, deleteFunction: (arg: Arg1Type) => void): void;
function functionA(arg: Arg1OtherType, deleteFunction: (arg: Arg1OtherType) => void): void;
function functionA(arg: any, deleteFunction: (arg: any) => void): void {
    deleteFunction(arg);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwIwBVzQLxQM7DgSwDsEBuAKFElkSQHlgALCONKrQgVwFsAjZ8skWDMAZgEMAxtABiHQhOD4A9oRhQA3mSjaoACjGIAXNWSsIAGigATCABsIw2fMUrj+oydToAlFAwA+KAA3JXwrb2MQsPIdPQMEY3hkeiYWdEsbe0c5BWVCN3jEmhTmM18A4NDwyKryAF8yMgkVXCgRHJdVYydclTUsdwSoMUIQDLsHCB7Ogo8RkHLAqOrKsL9AzVjMyem8we96gXbnPJhdACIRJSVzy10wxY0tHQB6F6gAOi+rJShGaG2nS+H2e2mahGwSnsH1sSgQ93C9QOjWOvVUugALAAmO4PdZPWJvT7fX7-awTIFfUFQcGQ6Gw+EPJECIkAUTgcCUcGMADlfkogsxYWIrFAuGJgBImNg-gx8DKJGJbLYQUTdHxFRxsNAyZQIDKfoQAOTAMUSqXeMiozpnS7XW56MLGTi8ZiPTavd7An6ygEUvLA6m0qEQGFwhHIurIshsjlc3n8wVwYWi8WS6Wy+U0pUqmPvdUQTXaqCERNCpQiv5iADW+uGhCgSh4ACtC8BLdbTrp1HVceF8R7tETvaSmOSsgGqbFg-Tw0yyFGSEA)

A function interface with `const` an an arrow function:

```typescript
interface FunctionA {
    (arg: Arg1Type, deleteFunction: (arg: Arg1Type) => void): void;
    (arg: Arg1OtherType, deleteFunction: (arg: Arg1OtherType) => void): void;
}

const functionA: FunctionA = (arg: any, deleteFunction: (arg: any) => void): void => {
    deleteFunction(arg);
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwIwBVzQLxQM7DgSwDsEBuAKFElkSQHlgALCONKrQgVwFsAjZ8skWDMAZgEMAxtABiHQhOD4A9oRhQA3mSjaoACjGIAXNWSsIAGigATCABsIw2fMUrj+oydToAlFAwA+KAA3JXwrb2MQsPIdPQMEY3hkeiYWdEsbe0c5BWVCN3jEmhTmM18A4NDwyKryAF8yMgkVXCgRHJdVYydclTUsdwSoMUIQDLsHCB7Ogo8RkHLAqOrKsL9AzVjMyem8we96gTJ25zyYXQAiESUlC8tdMMWNLR0AeleoADpvqyUoRmg20630+L20zUI2CU9k+tiUCAe4XqB0aJ16ql0ABYAEz3R7rZ6xd5fH5-AHWCbA75gqAQqEwuEIx7IgTEgCicDgSjgxgAcn8lEFmHCxFYoFwxMAJExsP8GPhZRIxLZbKDibo+EqONhoOTKBBZb9CAByYDiyXS7zHDpnS7XW54qzGTi8ZhPTZvD4g35ywGUvIgml06EQWHwxEouoosjszncvkCoVwEViiVSmVyhW05WqmMfDUQLU6qCERPCpSi-5iADWBuGhCgSh4ACtC8ArWjOud1HVHe6acTvWSmBSsgHqbFgwzw8yyFHyEA)

In both cases, if `Arg1Type` is `string` and `Arg1OtherType` is `number` (for example), these calls work:

```typescript
functionA("foo", (id) => {
    // ...do the deletion...
});

functionA(42, (id) => {
    // ...do the deletion...
});
```

...and these don't:

```typescript
// Error: No overload matches this call.
// (because the types don't match)
functionA("foo", (id: number) => {
    // ...do the deletion...
    console.log(id);
});

// Error: No overload matches this call.
// (because no overload takes an object)
functionA({}, (id) => {
    // ...do the deletion...
    console.log(id);
});
```

And in both cases, only the overload signatures (the first two) will be shown by IDEs, etc.; the implementation signature isn't.

[image]

[image]

In a comment you've said:

> ...how the invoking of this functions knows which types to use? Arg1Type and Arg1OtherType are both objects but inside these objects, the types are differents for each property. ...  I'd like to understand the conditional part a bit more

TypeScript will infer the correct overload to use based on the types of the arguments. In my examples, the types are `string` and `number`. When I started with `functionA("foo",` TypeScript could tell that I was using the `string` overload and will only allow a function that accepts a string. When I started with `functionA(42,` TypeScript could tell I was using the `number` overload and will only allow a function that accepts a number.

That's fine with objects with different shapes as well:

```typescript
interface Arg1Type {
    prop: string;
}
interface Arg1OtherType {
    prop: number;
}

functionA({"prop": "foo"}, (obj) => {
    // ...do the deletion...
    console.log(obj);
});

functionA({"prop": 42}, (obj) => {
    // ...do the deletion...
    console.log(obj);
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYEYAqBPABxQG8AoZC5AqAewIC5kBnMKUDAblIF9TRJYiFOmwB5MAAto+IsjKUqtBshABXALYAjaF159w0eEmQAxVSARhgNEKjnlKACjiZGI3IQgAaZABMIADYQkGYWVjaMzq5omB5EAJTIALwAfMgAbjTAvvGMmdlcClEYbrHiUlAy3n6BwRChltYgkS4lMWKS0p6JqRlZOXn9uqSkCDYsyDDmjTaojA3htsnIxYxwIHg+-kEh04st0et4PWn5A33ZyWnylNt1C03F8bpcpFNhTaiOxABE1HQ-Rg-GA0Gg-bg+Rw0TQAKxO9gUAHpEcgAHTo3w0ZCdGo7Jro1EOChjEBMGhBVEBGgYKGw548elvPafb5-JSA5AAFgATBCVtC4VcEZRkWiMVicXdFgSicgSWSKVSaQL6dx6UA)

Comment: ok sort of makes sense but slightly confused. I still don't know how the invoking of this functions knows which types to use? `Arg1Type` and `Arg1OtherType` are both objects but inside these objects, the types are differents for each property.

Comment: I mean it's working... but I'd like to understand the conditional part a bit more

Comment: @RedBaron - I've updated the answer to try to answer that question. The short version is that it knows which overload applies to the call because it knows the types of the arguments you're giving the function. It's fine if they're objects with different shapes (names or types of properties) rather than my `string`/`number` example. HTH! :-)

Comment: ah that's helpful and makes sense! thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
type A = string
type B = number
type Arg1 = A | B
const functionA = (arg1: Arg1, deleteFunc: (arg1: Arg1) => void): void {
 deleteFunc(arg1);
}
```

Comment: If you type everything as any you don't have a good reason to use TS in the first place.

Comment: I'm afraid [that doesn't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwFCkigCEEpMBXAWwCMJV9xoZVsBGUuAH2NwGMB7TCigAzcpl7B0guIgAUAQxasAXLGUAaKABMIAGwjAIAMXG81i5WuZsAlAgB8UAG790222tfvHUAN64OvqGJmaWdgDcuAC+uGISUoJBBkYAymhY2AAqABaZ4WooGDj2AVDlUAJC-AYAdHr82OG2UbFxZomYMHIARCL8-D1auikQ6cXZeSURQA) (even if I add the missing `=>`). Separately, code-only answers aren't *useful* answers. A useful answer explains what it's doing.